# Iterator for custom container

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, c++20

In my project I have some custom classes, with roughly the structure below.

Point, which represents a 2D int coordinate

```
struct Point {
  int x;
  int y;
}
```

Line, which represents a line drawn between two Points

```
class Line {
    Point start;
    Point end;
}
```

Polygon, which represents the polygon that is defined by number of Points.

```
class Polygon {
  private:
    std::vector<Point> _vertices;
}
```

I'm trying to implement a custom iterator for Polygon, the goal being a syntax something like:

```
Polygon aPolygon;
Point somePoint;
for( auto line_it = aPolygon.begin(); line_it != aPolygon.end(); line_it++ ){
    if( line_it->includes(somePoint) ){
        // Do something
    }
}
```

When iterating over Polygon the n:th element would be
`Line( _vertices[n], _vertices[n+1] )`,
and the last would be
`Line( _vertices[_vertices.size() - 1], _vertices[0] )`

How do I implement such an iterator, or otherwise acheive similar syntax with acceptable performance?

I'm looking through similar questions, but I've yet to find one similar enough for a comprehensive answer.
If possible I would prefer a STL solution that uses c++20 standard.

---

I realize the question was unecessarily vague, more specifically I'm asking how I can implement the `*`,`->` and `++` operators for my iterator.

```cpp
class Polygon {
  public:
    /* ... */

    struct PolygonIterator {
        using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = Line;
        using pointer = value_type*;
        using reference = value_type&;
        
        explicit PolygonIterator( Point* ptr ) : m_ptr( ptr ) {}
        reference operator*();
        // ^ Should return Line reference, but I have Point in container?
        PolygonIterator& operator++();
        pointer operator->();
        bool operator==(const PolygonIterator& other);
      private:
        Point* m_ptr;
    };
    PolygonIterator begin() { return PolygonIterator( &_vertices.front() ); }
    PolygonIterator end() { return PolygonIterator( &_vertices.back() ); }
```

Comment: Step 1: Pick an [iterator category](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator). You can start with a 'forward iterator'. Step 2: Make a class. Read through the requirements for your category, and implement all of them for the class.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Could you elaborate? I've been reading cppreference and other similar questions here on stackoverflow but still don't understand what the implementations of the requirements are supposed to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code again, satisfying *forward iterator* requirements would be tricky, because you essentially generate the lines on the fly. Hence I suggest making an [*input iterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator).

`operator++` should just increment `m_ptr`, nothing unusual. But you might want to store an `std::vector` iterator instead of a pointer (then, if you enable iterator debuggning for standard containers, it will extend to your iterators).

Then you have two options:

1. Store the current `Line` inside of the iterator. Then `*` and `->` return a reference and a pointer to it respectively. `++` will need to update this `Line` after incrementing the pointer/iterator.
2. Return the `Line` from `operator*` by value, and change `using reference` to `Line` to match the return type. This is unusal, but allowed for input iterators.

   Then `operator->` becomes tricky. It can't return a pointer (because there's no `Line` to point to), so it has to return a helper class by value, which in turn would store a `Line` (again by value), and overload `->` to return a pointer to it. You probably should also change `using pointer` to match the type of this helper class.

Comment: Thank you! Option 2 was exactly what I was looking for, and even seems to perform slightly better than what I was using before :)
The operator-> isn't the most beautiful, but I rarely use it anyway, and it seems to work intuitively.
After reading through the articles linked by @Serge Ballesta in another answer I think this functionality could be acheived with the new ranges/views but I haven't been able to wrap my head around that yet.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome into the world of containers which are not containers!

Since the beginning, standard library containers are expected to actually directly contain their objects. I could find 2 reference articles about that:

- [When Is a Container Not a Container?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill09.htm) by Herb Sutter, and
- [To Be or Not to Be (an Iterator)](https://ericniebler.com/2015/01/28/to-be-or-not-to-be-an-iterator/) by Eric Niebler

Long story made short your pseudo container is only a proxy container: objects exists *elsewhere*, and the container can only build *proxies* to them. It is not so uncommon and `vector<bool>` is such a container, and its iterators are only proxy iterators. Simply if you look into the sources of an implementation of the standard library, you will find every now and then *special processing* for `vector<bool>` in algorithm because `vector<bool>` iterators pretend being random access iterators when they cannot even meet the requirements of a forward container.

That means that your iterators will only be proxy iterators and their reference type will be an object (the proxy) instead of a true reference. Because of that they will be no more than simple *input iterators*. It is is acceptable for you, that will be enough, else you could have a look to the `range` library of C++20, which should start to provide some support to proxy containers and iterators.